# What is the simple way to detect time is in hours or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uidatepicker, nstimeinterval

I am using `UIDatePickerView` in my project with `timeInterval` one minute. After selecting time if time is in hours then I have to do some stuff. So how can I detect if user selects time in hours or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got answer for my own question

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter23 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [formatter23 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd--HH:mm"];
    NSDate* date1 = datePicker.date;
    [formatter23 setDateFormat:@"mm"];
if ([[formatter23 stringFromDate:date1] isEqualToString:@"00"] || [[formatter23 stringFromDate:date1] isEqualToString:@"30"]){
    NSLog(@"Date is in half an hour or hour");
}    else{
    NSLog(@"Some other");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this one , you can get hours between two date.**

```
NSDate* date1 = someDate;
 NSDate* date2 = someOtherDate;
 NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
 double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
 NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;
```

Comment: Thanks @prince I will try

Comment: Sure @prince I am checking

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
timeFormatter.dateFormat = @"HH";


NSString *date_Hour= [timeFormatter stringFromDate: localDate];
```

and simple way to get hour only use NSDateComponents class

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]]; 

NSInteger hour= [components hour];
```